# After drupal update site throws HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: drupal, drupal-9, drupal-permissions

I updated drupal from 9.2.7 to latest version using composer. The update was completed but the site throws "This site currently unable to handle this request.HTTP ERROR 500"
I changed the owner as "sudo chown -R username:groupname <drupal_directory>" with backup's username and password. But no use. I applied "chmod 755 -R <drupal_directory>" and the site loaded. But am getting permission errors when I tried a new update with composer. I am sure this problem is because of permission but what is the proper way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I create some bash script so that I can run it every time I run some updates or make any change to the Drupal installation.

The script may be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# site directory
site_directory="/path/to/drupal/installation" # full path to drupal installation

# user and group
user_name="user_name" # root is a good choice
group_name="group_name" # nginx, www-data, apache, etc., depending on the installed web server 

# reset user and group
chown -R ${user_name}:${group_name} ${site_directory}/

# reset general permitions
find ${site_directory} -type d -exec chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o= '{}' \;
find ${site_directory} -type f -exec chmod u=rw,g=r,o= '{}' \;

# reset files permitions
find ${site_directory}/web/sites/default/files/ -type d -exec chmod ug=rwx,o= '{}' \;
find ${site_directory}/web/sites/default/files/ -type f -exec chmod ug=rw,o= '{}' \;

# reset general selinux context (comment if not running selinux)
chcon -R system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 ${site_directory}/

# reset files selinux context (comment if not running selinux)
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t ${site_directory}/web/sites/default/files/
```

Of course, clearing the caches is also a good idea.

Comment: Thank you @balde-binos. This brought my site up. But I was unable to run drush after this.  "vendor/bin/drush: Permission denied"  I ran "chmod 755 -R vendor" and drush worked fine after this.  Thanks for your bash script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
The above script, sets permissions in a, somewhat, restrictive way.

Namely, I feel uncomfortable, setting **execute** permissions to drush.

Any time I need to run drush, I specifically set execution permissions to drush:

```
cd /path/to/drupal/installation
chmod 700 vendor/bin/drush
```

Then, I can run the necessary drush commands.

If You find this tedious, just add:

```
chmod 700 ${site_base_directory}/vendor/bin/drush
```

at the end of the script above.

Comment: Thank you @balde-binos . I reset general permissions again  and then set chmod 700 to vendor/bin/drush . Drush works fine